# set cookie in wordpress to follow to referral link on membership script

Tags: wordpress, cookies, referrals

I am trying to set a cookie in wordpress to track referrals.
  The link will come in as domain.com/?ref_id and should follow through a link to domain.com/subfolder/?ref_id

I understand it should be very simple so please forgive my ignorance in the matter.
 Thanks, ,

John.

Answer (score 0):

John,
You want to do something similar to the following:

```
$ref_id = $_GET['ref_id'];
$expire=time()+60*60*24*30;
setcookie("referral_id", $ref_id, $expire, '/', '.yourdomain.com');
```

Don't forget to sanitise the query string you are pulling in from $ref_id